# Help on proving that $1_{22k}$, where $k\in \mathbb{Z}^+$ is divisible by 23 with multiplicity 1.

Tags: number-theory, discrete-mathematics, divisibility

I have this curious question about repunits. A repunit is a positive integer resulting by repeating the digit $1$. The integers $1,11,111,1111$ are the first four out of infinite number of repunits. To simplify everything, the notation $1_n$ means the integer $1$ repeated $n$-times. A particular example will be $1_5$ means the integer $11111$ which is just $1$ repeated $5$-times.

My question is about the divisibility of the repunits of the form $1_{22k}$, where $k\in \mathbb{Z}^+$.

Using Wolfram Alpha we have the prime factorization of the first 3 repunits involved.

$1_{22}=11^2\times 23\times 4093\times \ldots \times 513293$

$1_{44}=11^2\times 23\times 89\times \ldots \times 1056689261$

$1_{66}=3\times 7\times 11^2\times 13\times 23\times 37\times \ldots \times 1344628210313298373$

Now, we will call multiplicity the power of a particular prime that appeared in the prime factorization of our integer. For instance in $1_{22}$, 11 has multiplicity 2 while 23 has multiplicity 1.

Based from above prime factorization, it seems that, CLAIM: The repunit of the form $1_{22k}$ is divisible by 23 with multiplicity 1.

My question is, how can we prove that indeed the claim is correct or not? Can you help me prove or disprove my claim? Thanks for reading my question and thank you in advance for your comments and suggestions.

Comment: Thank you so much for your valuable comment @Jack D'Aurizio. My bad, for forgetting FLT. My next question is about the multiplicity of 23 as a prime factor. How can we be sure that its multiplicity is 1?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**$1_{22k}$ is a multiple of $23$**: TRUE.

$$1_{22k}=\frac{10^{22k}-1}9$$ and Fermat's little theorem implies that $10^{23-1}\equiv1\pmod{23}$.

**$1_{22k}$ is a multiple of $23$ with multiplicity one**: FALSE

By Euler-Fermat's theorem,

$$10^{22\cdot23}\equiv1\pmod{23^2}$$
and hence $1_{22\cdot23}$ is a multiple of $23^2$.

In general, you may be interested in two facts:

- If $n\in\Bbb N$ and $\gcd(n,30)=1$ then there is infinitely many repunits which are divisible by $n$. Namely $1_{k\varphi(n)}$ is divisible by $n$ for every $k\in\Bbb N$.
- If you divide $1$ by $n$ (the same $n$ as in the previous point), you get a periodic decimal number. If the length of the period is $t$ then $1_t$ is a multiple of $n$. Moreover $t$ divides $\varphi(n)$.

Comment: Everything is clear to me now. Thanks @ajotatxe for your valuable answer.

Comment: Just a follow up question. Does Euler's theorem implies that the integer 23 is the least integer $k$ such that $10^{22k}\equiv 1(mod\ 23^2)$? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Already verified that the answer is affirmative.